Archive files recursively in a folder
There are few .csv and .txt files in my folder and I want to archive them into an archive folder recursively.
I know the command to archive the files but do not know how to call it recursively. I have to make use of parameters and then pass the values at run time.
I was just able to write the basic code and it ran fine for a single file but not directory.
tar -C /home/log -zcvf /Apps/agent/server/backup/interface/file /Apps/agent/server/srcfile/interface/file

Target - /Apps/agent/server/backup/interface/file
Source - /Apps/agent/server/srcfile/interface/file

When changing file to *.csv it will archive all CSV-files?  Can you explain more about your problem?

BTW: This question might be better asked header: https://unix.stackexchange.com/, because it's not strictly on-topic

@Luuk , Let me exlain:

My file structure is like
sourceFile/ Interface -
ABC.csv
ABC_Header - text file
ABC_Body - Text file
I need to archive all these files from the interface directory using a single script and then remove these files from the original location.

sorry the option -C, is not in my manual, see: man tar
